# How to have a same duplicated div structure but parsing a different xml data in each div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, loops

I am making some application that it loads data from an xml file. it works file if there is one corresponding div structure and one xml path. But I want to have multiple copies of my div structure, but each one will load different xml content.
I tired to do it by loop but it does copy each data in both content.

**JSFIDDLE: https://goo.gl/8XwMYz**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="data" data-xml="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33538012/file1.xml">
</div>
<div class="data" data-xml="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33538012/file2.xml">
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".data").each(function() {
  var path = $(this).attr("data-xml");
  $.ajax({
    url: path,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parse,
    error: function() {
      alert("Error: Something went wrong with loading the playlist!");
    }
  });

});

function parse(document) {
  $(document).find("person").each(function() {
    $(".data").append(
        "<div class='name'>Name: " +
        $(document).find("name").text() +
        "</div><div class='title'>Title: " +
        $(document).find("title").text() + "</div>")
      //$(document).find("name").text();
  });
}
```

As you can see in the HTML I have exactly the same structure but each one are linked to a different xml file paths., an in my code I want to load the corresponding data based on the xml file they are linked to.

**UPDATE:**

Based on the answer @charlietfl has provided, the code seems better now, but still does not provide the intended result. I have been testing on the below code, and realised that it does not pass the xml instance to the `parse` function.

```
$(".data").each(function() {
  // store element instance 
  var elem = $(this);
   var path = $(this).attr("data-xml");
    //console.log($el);

  $.ajax({
    url: path,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml){
        parse(document, elem);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("Error: Something went wrong with loading the playlist!");
    }
  });

});

function parse(document, elem) {
console.log($(document).find("name").text());

  $(document).find("person").each(function() {
    //alert($el);
    var $person = $(this);
    elem.append(
      "<div class='name'>Name: " +
      $person.find("name").text() +
      "</div><div class='title'>Title: " +
      $person.find("title").text() + "</div>")

  });
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. You need to store the instance of element outside the ajax and pass that into the success handling

```js
$(".data").each(function() {
  // store element instance 
  var $el = $(this),
    path = $(this).attr("data-xml");

  $.ajax({
    url: path,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
      parse(document, $el);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("Error: Something went wrong with loading the playlist!");
    }
  });

});

function parse(document, $el) {
  $(document).find("person").each(function() {
    var $person = $(this);
    $el.append(
      "<div class='name'>Name: " +
      $person.find("name").text() +
      "</div><div class='title'>Title: " +
      $person.find("title").text() + "</div>")

  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It didn't show the data in the correspondings div elements. they are empty, also there is no any error in console. any idea why is that?

Comment: I chose it as the right answer Since it is so close. except the line 'parse(document, $el)` must be  replaced with `parse(xml, $el)`.